# Installing SuiteCRM on CentOS - Composer error on plugins?

Tags: centos, composer-php

I'm following this guide to install SuiteCRM on CentOS: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-suitecrm-on-centos-linux/

I've gotten to Step4 `Run composer install:` but am getting an error on plugins version. Not sure what to do as It seems it's looking for an older version of the files??

[image]

Comment: Please share all error messages in text form, along with your debugging attempts

Comment: Also: why not **read** that error message? In the last line, it tells you everything interesting about the problem: the software you try to install is not compatible with Composer v2, see https://github.com/wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin/issues/184

Comment: That helped, I downgraded and the installation seems as it's going through. Thanks @NicoHaase